# What is an official collection of laws/books/etc. called?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

**What do you call an official collection of passages, laws, books, etc.?**

I'm thinking of a very official-sounding word, like "The ___crux" "The Index" or "The Axiom" or something sounding like that... I know I learned about it in gradeschool, but I can't quite recall it.

Comment: What *kind* of collection, maintained by who, and for what purpose? How about *canon, bible, scripture, torah, rulebook?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not entirely sure. It's a particular word, and it carries an air of high significance. It may or may not be a fictional thing.

Comment: @ Supuhstar: I'm sure there will be more words not yet proposed. I'm guessing you want something akin to ***annals, chronicles*** (the "official" records of important events), that focusses on *laws* rather than *events*. The problem with *canon* being the religious associations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers exactly

Comment: @Supuhstar: Unless ***codex*** does it for you too, you're on your own now! :) (but ***statutes*** has a certain *je ne sais quoi*)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of *[codex](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/codex)*

> (obsolete) a code, or body of laws [*Collins*]

As noted, its not much in use today.

There are also several compendia of law in specific fields called *[restatements](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Restatement)*

> (law) Any of several treatises published by the American Law Institute in which a group of legal scholars within a field of law set forth the principles of that field of law based on legal precedents [*Wiktionary*]

These include, for example *Restatement of the Law Second, Torts* and *Restatement Second, Contracts*.  These are each the second version of this compilation in these fields.

These are not simply compilations of statutes in these fields, since much of US law is not codified, but is based on judicial decisions. Rather, they are summaries of the general legal principles across most jurisdictions within the US, but there is significant variation by region and state.

There is also a system of collecting all of the significant judicial decisions for a given locale in a set of volumes called *[reporters](http://research.lawyers.com/glossary/reporter.html)* [*Glossary of Legal Terms*].

Obviously, this is limited to the US and many other systems exist in other jurisdictions.

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly what OP has in mind, because he hasn't been very clear. But it's the very word I couldn't think of myself a minute ago. I've just checked OED, which also says this particular sense is "obsolete". Obsolete or not, it's probably the only word with the precise meaning I had in mind, so +1!

Comment: That also sounds pretty good! Voting up, gonna wait to see if any more answers come in but I might just accept this!

Comment: Is there any reference showing that *codex* was definitely used for a collection that did not form a single treatise?

Comment: I'm with Keith here; codex is singular and implies that everything's been written up into a single book/scroll.

Comment: @Ben The point of a codex is that it is an organized reference work; this meaning persists in modern "code". The original Latin meant that various scrolls/other disparate information relating to law/medicine/etc. had been bound together in a single collection (usually a book). So the "Codex Justinianus" was simply an effort to codify many existing laws, ordered by Justinian. (In multiple volumes: "In the fourth booke of Iustinians new Codex, the thirtenth title."). It was also used more abstractly: "The whole codex of Christian precepts." (Both from OED).

Comment: possibly just "code" is what he is after.  The Glynfarian Code, or whatever.

Answer (score 13):

Consider ***corpus***.

> a complete or comprehensive collection, as of laws or writings of a specified type: *the corpus of civil law*
>
> <sub>Source: Webster's New World College Dictionary Copyright © 2010</sub>

For example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus) lists below corpora:

> - Hippocratic Corpus, the lectures and writings of Hippocrates
> - Corpus Inscriptionum Etruscarum, an index of Etruscan texts
> - Corpus Reformatorum, a collection of Reformation writings
> - An abbreviation for the Corpus Juris Civilis, a collection of four
>     books on law by Justinian I
> - Corpus Hermeticum, a collection of Egyptian-Greek Wisdom texts from
>     the second century
> - Corpus Areopagiticum, a collection of theologic and phlisophic texts
>     attributed to a "Dionysius"
> - Corpus Aristotelicum, a collection of texts by the philosopher
>     Aristotle
> - Corpus Scriptorum Christianorum Orientalium, a collection of eastern
>     Christian texts with over 600 volumes

Comment: +1 As in [*Corpus Juris Secundum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_Juris_Secundum).

Answer (score 5):

*Canon* carries a strong connotation of officialdom (hence, *canonical*).

> Noun
>
> canon (plural canons)
>
> 1. A group of literary works that are generally accepted as representing a field.
>
>    "the durable **canon** of American short fiction" — William Styron

[from Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canon#Noun)

Comment: perhaps add the dictionary definition.

Comment: More precisely, a canon is a selection of officially approved works (for some purpose) out of a greater number of comparable works. Perhaps best known are the various Christian biblical canons, which do not quite agree with each other in their choices.

Comment: @dwjohnston I took the liberty of adding the one I think phenry meant

Answer (score 4):

An official collection of laws is a "code", as in "Revised Code of Washington" (RCW), "United States Code" (USC), or "International Residential Code" (IRC).

One meaning of "library" is a collection of books.

Comment: Is there another one for the collection of codes that makes up all laws enforced in the United States, be they local, state, or federal?

Comment: cf. the [Code of Hammurabi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_of_Hammurabi)

Answer (score 2):

A pretty general word can be "**digest**". But I don't know if it can apply to your case (it does not seem (to me) very "official-sounding"): we should see the context. Google reports one definition: "a compilation or summary of material or information."

Other similar words might be: body, compendium.

Comment: *Digest* is surely only a portion of the relevant documents, by definition. But *compilation* itself sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question in English, but in German the word is "Verzeichnis" - as in, the "Ryom Verzeichnis" - the works of composer Antonio Vivaldi, as collected by Peter Ryom circa 1974.

Catalogue would work as well, in a more modern sense.

Answer (score 0):

Through some thesaurus surfing I think I found it:

> ### Lexicon

I know this only refers to language, and is not a collection of books, but it does seem to be the word that was on the tip of my tongue. Hopefully someone can submit an answer that carries the same power and has a much closer definition to the one in my question.